# How does boto3 handle S3 object creation/deletion/modification during listing?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

### Background

Lets say I have 2 AWS S3 buckets, `bucket_input` and `bucket_output`.

I plan on iterating over the contents of `bucket_input` - performing some transformations on each object as I go - before saving them to `bucket_output`.

According to the following post [Listing contents of a bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249069/listing-contents-of-a-bucket-with-boto3/44733887), I can simply do the following

```
for object_input in bucket_input.objects.all():
    upload_to_output(transform(object_input))
```

### Problem

How does the iteration of `for object_input in bucket_input.objects.all():` behave when new objects are added/deleted from the bucket mid-iteration? And what are the best practices for how would I go about handling this for my use case?