# Python 3 + boto3 + s3: download all files in a folder

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am writing a Python 3.4 + boto3 script to download all files in an s3 bucket/folder. I'm using s3.resource rather than client because this EMR cluster already has the key credentials.

This works to download a single file:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = "my-bucket"
file = "some_file.zip"
filepath = "some_folder/some_file.zip"


def DL(bucket, key, local_name):
    s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, local_name)

DL(bucket, filepath, file)
```

But I need to download all files in a folder within the bucket, which have a format like so:

```
some_file_1.zip
some_file_2.zip
some_file_3.zip, etc.
```

It should be simple but I guess we can't use a wildcard or pattern match like "some_file*". So I have to loop through and find each file name?

And call download_file for each file name?

Comment: Get a list of all keys in the bucket. See   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249069/listing-contents-of-a-bucket-with-boto3. Then get the keys of the files you want using wilcards on the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [listobjectsv2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) and pass the prefix to only get the keys inside your s3 "folder". Now you can use a for loop to go through all these keys and download them all. Use conditions if you need to filter them more.