# Get only file names from s3 bucket folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a s3 bucket named 'Sample_Bucket' in which there is a folder called 'Sample_Folder'. I need to get only the names of all the files in the folder 'Sample_Folder'.

I am using the following code to do so -

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1', verify=False)
    bucket = s3.Bucket('Sample_Bucket')
    for files in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Sample_Folder):
        print(files)
```

The variable files contain object variables which has the filename as key.

```
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='Sample-Bucket', key='Sample_Folder/Sample_File.txt')
```

But I need only the filename.
How do I extract that? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing contents of a bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249069/listing-contents-of-a-bucket-with-boto3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use list_object_v2 which gives you the list from the defined prefix used.

```py
... snippet ...

filenames = []

def get_filenames(s3):
    result = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    for item in result['Contents']:
        files = item['Key']
        print("file: ", files)
        filenames.append(files)   #optional if you have more filefolders to got through.
    return filenames

get_filenames(my_bucketfolder)
```

Comment: That can get max 1000 objects. It is unbelievable that they hardcoded this limit and you cant change.

Answer (score 12):

Here you go.

```
import boto3


bucket = "Sample_Bucket"
folder = "Sample_Folder"
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
files_in_s3 = [f.key.split(folder + "/")[1] for f in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=folder).all()]
```

Comment: Thanks. I love using boto3.resource when possible.

Answer (score 1):

for myself, i made a function that you might find helpful:

```
import boto3


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


def list_objects_without_response_metadata(**kwargs):
    ContinuationToken = None
    while True:
        if ContinuationToken:
            kwargs["ContinuationToken"] = ContinuationToken
        res = s3_client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        for obj in res["Contents"]:
            yield obj
        ContinuationToken = res.get("NextContinuationToken", None)
        if not ContinuationToken:
            break


file_names = [obj["Key"] for obj in list_objects_without_response_metadata(Bucket='Sample_Bucket', Prefix='Sample_Folder')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `boto3.client` and prefer `boto3.resource` you can use this snippet to list all the directory names within a directory.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("Sample_Bucket")
res = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name, Delimiter='/', Prefix = "Sample_Folder/"')
for o in res.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(o.get('Prefix'))
```