# How to iterate through a specific folder in a S3 bucket using python and not from aws lambda?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a structure like:
test which is a bucket name
border folder
config folder
feed folder
and then feed1.txt and feed2.txt files inside it.
I want to iterate through feed folder.How can I do that?
test/border/config/feed/feed1.txt,feed2.txt

Comment: You can use AWS Boto library.

Comment: I know we can use boto library,but I am asking a specific command.

Comment: If you know which command I can use in my use case,please let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing contents of a bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249069/listing-contents-of-a-bucket-with-boto3)