# how to check if aws s3 path exists with the help of python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to write python program that checks if path exists or not. For example, given the path `/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/`, I want to pass this path to the S3 API to check whether this path exists in AWS S3 or not.

I have tried this, but it is not full-fledged solution for my requirement:

```
import boto3
import botocore
client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=AccessKey, aws_secret_access_key=SecretAccessKey,region_name='us-east-1')
result = client.list_objects(Bucket=full_poc", Prefix="sub_folder1/sub_folder2/full" )
print(result)
exist = False
if "Contents" in result:
    exist = True

print(exist)
```

With this code, even if I pass `sub` instead of `sub_folder1` it prints `True`.

What are other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "even if I pass `sub` instead of `sub_folder1` it prints `True`"? Can you show a full example? Also, you have a quoting issue in that code. I'm guessing you want to do `client.list_objects(Bucket="full_poc"...`?

Comment: _WHY_ do you want to check if a path exists or not? You can store objects in _any path_ within S3 without creating folders.

Answer (score 1):

[S3 doesn't have folders](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html):

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, and objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects have names that begin with a common string). Object names are also referred to as *key names*.

The only way that `/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/` can "exist" is if you have an object whose key begins with `/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/`. [List the objects in your bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30249069/354577) and see if any begin with that prefix, e.g. something like

```py
any((s.startswith("/root/subfolder1/subfolder2/") for s in bucket.objects.all()))
```

Answer (score 1):

No such thing called Folder in S3. Folder is basically an empty file with name ending with '/'. We can check two things

- getObject results in empty body
- Make sure name of key ends with `/` before getObject. Reason for this check is, we don't want to get the actual object unless we know its a folder name, it will result in unnecessary data transfer.

If object doesn't exist getObject will result in error, we can just catch it.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
key = 'myfolder1/subfolder/'
try:
    if(key.endswith('/')):
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='my-bucket',
                            Key=key)
        if(len(obj.get('Body').read()) == 0):
            folder = True
    else:
        folder = False
except Exception as e:
    folder = False
if(folder):
    print("yes its a folder")
else:
    print("No Its not")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-west-2'
os.environ['S3_ENDPOINT'] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
print(tf.gfile.Exists('s3path'))#返回True or False
```

Comment: @Tg. this is an answer to the question, even if it is a bad answer. Please do not delete it in the Low Quality Posts Queue.