# List all objects in AWS S3 bucket with their storage class using Boto3 Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a requirement where I need to list all objects in a s3 bucket and their storage classes.

How can I achieve this with `Python` and `Boto3`? I use `Python 3.7`.

Comment: Does this help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249069/listing-contents-of-a-bucket-with-boto3)?

Comment: it lists the objects in the form of s3.ObjectsSummary(bucket_name=<bucket name>, key='key name'). Not listing the storage class details

Comment: Yes it does thank you @Girish

Answer (score 3):

This code will list all objects in a given bucket, displaying the object name (Key) and Storage Class. This code uses the *resource* method of accessing Amazon S3.

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket')

for object in bucket.objects.all():
    print(object.key, object.storage_class)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and use [S3 Inventory Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html).

> Amazon S3 inventory is one of the tools Amazon S3 provides to help
> manage your storage. You can also simplify and speed up business
> workflows and big data jobs using Amazon S3 inventory, which provides
> a scheduled alternative to the Amazon S3 synchronous List API
> operation.

One of the items that's listed in the report is:

- Storage class – Storage class used for storing the object

[Here's the full list of what's in the report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html#storage-inventory-contents).

Finally, you can use [S3 Inventory REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html#storage-inventory-related-resources).