# why I cannot get the whole list of files so that the contents in s3 bucket by using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, list, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get contents of files in s3 and for that at first I am getting the list of the files from different folders/subfolders for which I will get the contents. However, I have realized that my method does not give me all the files in that bucket and it only reads less than the half of the files in the folders/subfolders and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
 def get_s3_list(bucket, prefix):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
```

I think the part where I get **s3.list_objects_v2** needs to be modified but I am not familiar with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documentation for [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) clearly states "Returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket with each request."

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend your code and add [pagination](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html). Only using pagination you can get full list of your bucket.

Comment: Yes. The `list_objects_v2()` will only return a maximum of 1000 objects. Alternatively, instead of using the `client` version of calls, you could use the `resource` method of calls and use `bucket.objects.all()` -- I think that it returns _all_ objects and handles pagination for you. It's a more Pythonic way of accessing S3. For some examples, see [List all objects in AWS S3 bucket with their storage class using Boto3 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072127/174777) and [Listing contents of a bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30249069/174777).