# S3 listing all files in subfolder in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter

I have an s3 bucket, with files under a folder structure like `folder1/folder2`
I want to list the files under the folder structure only and iterate through the files in a Sagemaker Jupyter notebook.

How can I achieve this? I tried the instructions in [Listing contents of a bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249069/listing-contents-of-a-bucket-with-boto3) but was able to list only at the top level recursively. But I want to list only at the folder level.

I also tried the below code snippet

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname/folder1/folder2')
for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object)
```

and got the below error

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name...
```

Using Python 3.9 currently.
Thanks!

Comment: `bucketname` is the bucket name. `folder1/folder2/` is the key prefix.

Answer (score 6):

A few issues here:

1. `bucketname` is the bucket name
2. `folder1/folder2/` is the key prefix
3. you need to filter the list, not get all objects

Try:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')
for object_summary in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder1/folder2/'):
    print(object_summary)
```

That will result in a list of [ObjectSummary](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/objectsummary/index.html) values being printed, for example:

```
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucketname', key='folder1/folder2/')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucketname', key='folder1/folder2/abc.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucketname', key='folder1/folder2/def.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucketname', key='folder1/folder2/xyz.png')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucketname', key='folder1/folder2/folder3/')
```

Note that it will include all objects at the `folder1/folder2/` level, regardless of their file extension suffix, and it will potentially include an indication of the folder itself (`folder1/folder2/`) and any logical sub-folders such as `folder1/folder2/folder3/`.

You can retrieve the objects from an object summary as follows:

```
for object_summary in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="folder1/folder2/"):
    print(object_summary.Object().key)
```

That will result in a list of [Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/object/index.html#S3.Object) keys being printed, for example:

```
folder1/folder2/
folder1/folder2/abc.csv
folder1/folder2/def.csv
folder1/folder2/xyz.png
folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

You can filter these to get just CSVs, as needed, for example:

```
summaries = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="folder1/folder2/")
csvs = [x for x in summaries if x.Object().key.endswith(".csv")]

for objectsummary in csvs:
    print(objectsummary.Object().key)
```

That will result in:

```
folder1/folder2/abc.csv
folder1/folder2/def.csv
```

And you can split out the actual filename, as follows:

```
for objectsummary in csvs:
    print(objectsummary.Object().key.split("/")[-1])
```

That will result in:

```
abc.csv
def.csv
```

Comment: Thank you @jarmod...I would presume this would print the file names in the directory...but what I get is an empty output...the folder is full of CSV files...any thoughts on how I can check this further?

Comment: @FlyingPickle I've updated the answer with more details of the ObjectSummary and Object values. Can you comment here if you're still seeing a problem. Also, double-check your objects using the awscli e.g. `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/folder1/folder2/`.